# If history repeats as farce, then how can Nietzsche's madman prove the truth?

Tags: nietzsche, marx, marxism

I keep wondering what "farce" really amounts to, in class terms, for Marx, rather than individual. On [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31728/what-would-marx-say-about-lenin), there was the following comment

[image]

But, if we look at more class based movements, such as the Russian tragedy, and the crushing of the German revolution, I wondered if we could call Nietzsche's parable, of the madman, a useful expression of the farcical.

> [Here](http://www.historyguide.org/europe/madman.html) the madman fell silent and looked again at his listeners; and
>   they, too, were silent and stared at him in astonishment. At last he
>   threw his lantern on the ground, and it broke into pieces and went
>   out. "I have come too early," he said then; "my time is not yet. This
>   tremendous event is still on its way, still wandering; it has not yet
>   reached the ears of men. Lightning and thunder require time; the light
>   of the stars requires time; deeds, though done, still require time to
>   be seen and heard. This deed is still more distant from them than most
>   distant stars -- and yet they have done it themselves.
>
> It has been related further that on the same day the madman forced his
>   way into several churches and there struck up his requiem aeternam
>   deo. Led out and called to account, he is said always to have replied
>   nothing but: "What after all are these churches now if they are not
>   the tombs and sepulchers of God?"

If the [era of social revolution](https://www.marxists.org/archive/mattick-paul/1936/inevitability.htm) is coming again, then how could the "madman", as history repeats, reconfigure tradegy, into what he heralds?

Comment: maybe a bit much there, idk, sorry if so

Comment: If you haven't already you should read "The Poverty of Historicism"

Comment: Seamus Heaney wrote the [Haw-Lantern](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1995/poems-2-e.html) in 1987; which is a reference to [Diogenes the Cynic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haw_Lantern) "who carried a lantern through the streets looking for an honest man"; I take it Nietschze, in his guise as Zarathrutha, too, is looking for an honest man, in relation to his big idea - the death of god & deicide.

Comment: @MoziburUllah thanks for that, i may even have seen the poem before :-/